# Show that if G is a disconnected graph containing exactly two odd vertices, then these odd vertices must be in the same component of G.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently working in the following graph theory excercise:

> Show that if $G$ is a disconnected graph containing exactly two odd vertices, then these odd vertices must be in the same component of $G$.

I'm thinking about the lemma: If

$$deg(u)+deg(v) ≥ n-1$$

Then $G$ is connected and $diam(G) ≥ 2$

But haven't find a way to suit the lemma in my solution, thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: If the odd vertices were in different components then the subgraph given by taking one of the components would have exactly one odd vertex, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The sum of degrees in any graph is even — in particular, this is true about each connected component of $G$.